# Correcting GPS data using Photos

Tags: software-recommendation, photos, gps, photos.app

Really simple question: Is there a way to fix incorrect GPS data? A recent trip lead to a bunch of pictures taken in the same place getting sometimes wildly wrong coordinates appended to them (probably because the photos were taken indoors).

I'm looking for official Apple products or solutions that run on iOS or OS X if they exist.

Comment: @Buscar On an iPhone? How?

Comment: Are you looking for an OS X or an iOS solution?

Comment: @patrix Either. I'd like to use the official Apple tools if at all possible.

Comment: Doesn't the new Photos app allow to edit the photo's location?

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli the image above was taken from the new Photos app. The map pin was not editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apple Photos 2.0 on macOS 10.12 Sierra you can adjust locations of photos. This was not yet possible a year ago, when the question was asked.

You can also use [HoudahGeo](https://www.houdah.com/houdahGeo/) to both update the location in Photos and write the corrected GPS data to EXIF tags within the image files. Note: I am the developer of HoudahGeo.

Answer (score 2):

There is a app (there is always a app :) to do that, and it is free.

Photo Investigator: View, Edit, Remove Metadata; GPS, EXIF...
By Daniel Anderson

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photo-investigator-view-edit/id571574618?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

For those who already have it, or who would be willing to get it, [Adobe Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop-lightroom.html) handles that with impressive ease.

Import and open your photo, and toggle the "Metadata" panel on the right (typically under "Histogram") and scroll to the bottom. Next to "GPS" click the coordinates that are displayed. Drag the icon to the desired location.